# Why do I have to restart the Django server every time I make some changes in views?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and every time I make a change in veiws.py or urls.py I have to run python manange.py run server. This is hectic as for every small change I have to restart the server. Is there any fix? Or is this normal?

Comment: Is the app you are working on included in settings.py? Changes will be captured automatically if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> check your `TEMPLATES` of 'settings.py`.

If you have defined your `DIRS` something like this:

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR , 'templates'],
```

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR , 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

So change it to `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']`, if you don't do this it will cause the server to `restart` again and again.

like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

It may solve your problem.